# xslt reset numbering back to 1

Tags: xslt

I have 100 nodes of Employees.  I need to generate an xml, that when id reaches 40 then the id reset to 1.  If id reaches 80 then id reset back to 1, and so on.  I can use a for-each loop and if mod 40 = 0 then subtract 40, but I am sure there is a better solution.  Below is my example

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <EmployeeDetails>
        <Employee id="1">
            <Name>TEST</Name>
        </Employee>
        <Employee id="2">
            <Name>TEST</Name>
        </Employee>
        <Employee id="3">
            <Name>TEST</Name>
        </Employee>
        <Employee id="4">
            <Name>TEST</Name>
        </Employee>
        <Employee id="5">
            <Name>TEST</Name>
        </Employee>
        .
        .
        .
        <Employee id="122">
            <Name>TEST</Name>
        </Employee>
    </EmployeeDetails>
```

and desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EmployeeDetails>
    <Employee id="1">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="2">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    .
    .
    .
    <Employee id="40">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="1">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="2">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    ..
    .
    .

<Employee id="40">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee> .
    .Employee id="1">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>.
    .
    .
    <Employee id="40">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    <Employee id="1">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
    .Employee id="2">
        <Name>TEST</Name>
    </Employee>
</EmployeeDetails>
```

Can you please help?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your xslt as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="((position() - 1) mod 40) + 1"/>
```

goes from 1 .. 40 (inclusive) and then starts from 1 again.

Of course you can use some other number than `position()` as the basis.

Comment: When proper parenthesis put in place, it started working

Comment: <xsl:variable name="d" select="((position() - 1) mod 40) + 1"/>

Comment: @user3269443 Worked for me without, but you are right, it needs parentheses.